# How do I lock down an Access database on macro-disabled systems?

Tags: database, ms-access, deployment, ms-access-2007

question for you.

So I have this Access 2007 database that I'm trying to lock down so that it can be deployed.  The intent is for multiple users to run the front-end application simultaneously, connecting to the back-end tables over the network.  However, I obviously don't want to give them access to the forms, settings, tables, etc.

I already tried using the `ChangeProperty` function for

- AllowFullMenus
- AllowSpecialKeys
- AllowBypassKey
- AllowShortcutMenus
- AllowBuiltInToolbars
- AllowToolbarChanges
- AllowBreakIntoCode

But whenever anyone without macro's explicitly enabled opens the database, everything opens as if none of these settings are set.  How can I get around this?  I only use like 3 macros in the program, and none of them are related to the opening of the database or locking down the database.

Suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try distributing your front-end as a locked ACCDE file, this is the equivalent of the old MDE files from Access 2000.  Details are available here: http://www.databasedev.co.uk/convert_to_accde_format.html